# Error: Uncaught ionic 2

Tags: ionic, ionic2, ionic-popup

Tenho seguinte:

```
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
          dismissOnPageChange: true,
        });

    loader.present().then(authData => {

        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: '',
          message: 'Cadastrado com sucesso!',
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'Ok',
              handler: data => {
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
              }
            }
          ]
        });

        alert.present();

    });
```

Código funcionou porém, obtive seguinte erro:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page',
  templateUrl: 'page.html',
})

export class AlgumaPage {

 loader : any;

 constructor(public loadCtrl : LoadingController) {}

 ionViewDidLoad() {
  //executa quando carrega a tela
 }

 /**
 * Metodo utilizado para abrir o load sincronizando
 * Esse loader tem a propriedade duration, assim, ele vai ser fechado automatico
 */
 abrirLoading(){
   this.loadCtrl.create({
  content: "Sincronizando...",
  duration: 2000
   }).present();
 }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 /**
 * Metodo utilizado para abrir o sincronizando
 */
 abrirLoading(){
  this.loader = this.loadCtrl.create({
    content: "Sincronizando..."
  });
  this.loader.present();
 }

 /**
 * Metodo utilizado para fechar o sincronizando
 */
 fecharLoading(){
  this.loader.dismiss();
 }
 
}
```

Acima estou mostrando dois loader, um com tempo para fechar e outro abrindo e fechando, espero que atenda.